# Renaming a File() object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, rename, file-rename

I'd like for my users to be able to re-name a file before uploading it.

I have a `File` object in Javascript which has a `name` property that is already set, but i'd like for this to be able to be updated.  Right now doing the obvious `myFile.name = "new-name.txt"` returns an error that this property is read only.

What's the best way of changing the `name` property on a JavaScript `File` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an `input` tag with the name on it and hide the `name` property from the user. On the server, just use the `input` as the name and ignore the default name.

Comment: I already have a client side `<input />` for the user to type the name into.  Right now this actually might be the only feasible option as far as I can tell :(  Still looking though...

Comment: Yeah,,, `File` objects are immutable.  Doing this seems to be the best way,  I could piece together a hack to extract the file data, turn it into a `Blob` with the new name, and then turn that into a `File` but going this route is much easier.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. You didn't say how to rename the file object or how to create copy of the object with different name. You basically said that OP should create workaround...

Answer (score 78):

Now that `file.name` is a read-only property, I've found this to be the best method to rename a File object in the browser:

```
const myNewFile = new File([myFile], 'new_name.png', {type: myFile.type});
```

Comment: Clean, but `File() constructor` not supported at IE & Edge plus Opera for Android.

Comment: Thanks. Will it duplicate the memory? or just use the pointer to the existing blob referred by original file?

Comment: @AkshayKhot were you able to find this out? I would also like to know if it's duplicated in memory

Comment: It doesn't look like it increased memory usage for me.

Comment: @ChrisLang, yes, I think the new file just points to the existing blob, instead of duplicating it.

Answer (score 17):

try this:

```
var blob = file.slice(0, file.size, 'image/png'); 
var newFile = new File([blob], 'name.png', {type: 'image/png'});
```

note: 
this is for a image type, you have to change this type with type you're actually using.

Comment: I would say, if you're working with a File object anyway, to use:
`var blob = file.slice(0, file.size, file.type)`

Answer (score 3):

In response to Alexander Taborda's answer... The first and second parameters of Blob.slice() are the start and end bytes of the original blob that should form the new blob. By saying:

```
var blob = file.slice(0,-1);
```

you are not saying "copy to the end of the file" (which is what I think is your aim), you are saying "copy the whole blob except the last byte".

As @carestad says

```
var blob = file.slice(0, file.size);
```

followed by creating a new File() object should create an exact copy with a new name.

Note that with a png, the file will be considered invalid without the final byte.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`FileSystemEntry.moveTo(newParent[, newName][, successCallback][, errorCallback]);`

to rename a file or directory.

It's from MDN :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemEntry/moveTo

Comment: This is marked in MDN as both Experimental and Deprecated. Perhaps this is why this answer got no votes in a couple of years. Since JavaScript is insecure, it should not have direct access to the client file system, although there are plenty of loopholes, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming f is original file object, just use spread operator, example of regexing the name:

```
let newF = {
        ...f,
        name: f.name.toString().replace(/[^0-9A-Za-z.\-_()]/gi, '')
      };
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work since f.name is read only.   :(