# How to change uploaded file name before submit form using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file

Can I change file name before send form in jQuery?

`console.log(this.files[0])` give me this:

```
File { name: "logo.png", lastModified: 1477594844000, lastModifiedDate: Date 2016-10-27T19:00:44.000Z, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 45817, type: "image/png" }
```

but I need change name from logo.png to logo2.png before use `$('#uploadForm').submit();`

I found that File object is readonly. It is possible to make it writable or change name in other way before form send?

Comment: No, it is not possible, you can't access the file name at client-side. Just rename the file when saving it to server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming a File() object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733904/renaming-a-file-object-in-javascript)