# rename video in browser before upload

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, video-processing

I'm using this to rename a video file before uploading to S3 (so S3 updates straight away)

The file comes in via https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone

```
  const extension = scene.file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase()
  const blob = scene.file.slice(0, -1, scene.file.type)
  scene.file = new File([blob], 'scene_' + scene.id + '_' + uuidv1() + '.' + extension, {type: scene.file.type})
  scene.filename = scene.file.name
  scene.type = scene.file.type.match('image') ? 0 : 1
```

This works with most video files, however there are a few (from a different camera) where the file is corrupted when I try and play via brower or VLC.

The VLC error is

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000045728c0] error reading header
>   scene_2567_e35e50d0-2731-11e8-bfa4-2b3f6813e7ca.mp4: End of file

These files are fine before I rename them.

Is there a better way to rename a file before upload?

Comment: I may be missing something, but why do you need to create an entirely new `File` object just to rename it?

Comment: That's the code I found somewhere else. Is there another way to rename a file in Javascript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733904/renaming-a-file-object-in-javascript

Comment: Sorry, I thought you could just overwrite `file.name`. It seems you cannot.

Comment: What does "*so S3 updates straight away*" actually mean, here?   Is `-1` the correct 2nd argument for a blob slice?  It seems like that might truncate one byte from the end, but I may be quite wrong about that... it seems like `scene.file.size` or maybe `null` would be more appropriate, assuming this is the best approach.